# Cryptographic Secret Santa

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, cryptography

Is there a protocol for conducting a Secret Santa without a central authority? Precisely, we want to sample uniformly a permutation that has no one-cycles and reveal to each member his or her successor without revealing any other part of the permutation. Alternatively, we can uniformly sample an $n$-cycle, where $n$ is the number of participants in the Secret Santa.

Comment: http://rodrigosetti.com/cryptography/cryptographic-secret-santa/

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted! I have a followup question. Is there a protocol that doesn't rely on encryption? Preferably one that could be used in person without a computer, like the protocol for secure addition.

Answer (score 13):

[Cryptographic Protocols with Everyday Objects](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/personal/st/S.Schneider/papers/2011/cryptoforma11a.pdf) (section 5)

> Typical cryptographic Secret Santa protocols require a fully
>   homomorphic encryption system. These protocols are thus suitable for
>   those with some planning, some expertise and access to computational
>   assistance, but not to a group of friends without access to computers.
>   Here we present an alternative solution, which does not lower the
>   security requirements, and does not require anything beyond card,
>   envelopes and pens.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1054676/30836 gives an equivalent protocol which may be physically slicker.

Comment: @Micah: Personally, I find the envelope-based solution quite a bit more practical than anything that involves cutting up cards and stapling them together (not to mention trying to shuffle the stapled-up cards). But I guess that's a matter of taste.